# Pipeline disappeared from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: spark-streaming, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a streaming pipeline from Azure Data Factory that suddenly vanished from Monitoring tab from Azure Data Factory page. It is running on Databricks from quite a long time(May be more than 45 days without interruptions).

One day the pipeline is no longer shown in ADF Pipeline runs in Monitoring tab and the previous runs disappeared as well but none of the alerts set from Databricks side kicked off. Turns out the job is still running from Databricks side but the corresponding ADF pipeline details disappeared along with old runs for the same streaming pipeline.

How is this possible? Any reason for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If it still run, the monitor of it should be find.

May be you can check the filter of the pipeline monitor:

[image]

Comment: Nope, It is still running but couldn't see the current/ previous run for the pipeline. Tried filter on the pipeline name and extended the filter duration, it did not work.